# Java Servlet - How to cached Servlet Context to all instance?

Tags: java, web-services, file, caching, buffer

I just have a text file and it will be updated by another shell program (15') and my Java Servlet is used to read this file and return to client in Web Browser. But I don't know how to make Servlet Context set timeout 15' and reread this file to store in memory?

Edit: Ok, thanks, I've found my solution is using a simple Thread + ServletContextListener.

Comment: can you describe step by step what you are trying to do ? who, what, when ? (user, server, another server ? , data, file, ...)

Comment: It is very detail and clear (do you need anything else?) that it is cached to all client by reading a file which is periodically updated by shell program.

Comment: it's up to the client to re-load the page every 15 minutes: you put a timer inside and reload the page => then your servlet read the "good" file, or you keep it inside your web app.

Comment: I could not keep the file in my web app as it it is in file system, what I want here is servlet should not fetch data before 15'.

Comment: You could setup a FileWatchdog I suppose https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.html

Comment: or java watch service, to monitor file change. http://andreinc.net/2013/12/06/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-writing-a-simple-filefolder-monitor-using-the-watch-service-api/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've found my solution is using a simple Thread + ServletContextListener.